# Single org endorsement policy for a fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, configuration-files, hyperledger-caliper

what should be the endorsement policy of a "1 org fabric network" for its configuration file?

I am trying to test hyperledger fabrics sample "fabcar" network with hyperledger caliper. fabcar network consists of 1 org.

I have seen some codes for the configuration files of fabric networks but all of them have 2 or more orgs.

here is a sample code for endorsement policy of a 2 org network-

```
"endorsement-policy": {
    "identities": [
      {
       "role": {
         "name": "member",
         "mspId": "org1MSP"
      }},
     {
      "role": {
        "name": "member",
        "mspId": "org2MSP"
      }},
     {
      "role": {
        "name": "admin",
        "mspId": "org1MSP"
     }}],
   "policy": { "2-of": [{"signed-by": 0}, {"signed-by": 1}]}
}
```

how am i supposed to edit my identities and my policy?

Answer (score 1):

This should be it.

```
"endorsement-policy": {
    "identities": [
      {
       "role": {
         "name": "member",
         "mspId": "org1MSP"
      }}
    ],
    "policy": { "1-of": [{"signed-by": 0}]}
}
```